# Area covered by a constant length segment rotating around the center of a square.

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

This is an idea I have had in my head for years and years and I would like to know the answer, and also I would like to know if it's somehow relevant to anything or useless.
I describe my thoughts with the following image:
[image]
What would the area of the "red almost half circle" on top of the third square be, assuming you rotate the hypotenuse of a square around it's center limiting its movement so it cannot pass through the bottom of the square.
My guess would be:

$$\ \frac{\left(\pi*(h/2)^2 - a^2\right)}{2}$$

And also, does this have any meaning? Have I been wandering around thinking about complete nonsense for so many years?

Comment: I would almost guess that this problem has something to do with so-called catenary problem (hanging chain) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary. It looks related to me.

Comment: I don't think the shape at the top of the curve is actually a circle.  I can write out the details of this as an answer if people are interested.

Comment: Superficially, it might also be related to the Kakeya problem?

Comment: Rough idea: compute the equation of the line from a point $(x_0,0)$ through $(a/2,a/2)$. Set the distance of the line segment from $(x_0,0)$ through $(x,y)$ to be $\sqrt{2}a$. Use this to find $y$ and then integrate $y$ as $x_0$ goes from $0$ to $a$. Subtract the area of the square.

Comment: @kigen: It's clearly not a circle **centered at the green point**.  It's less clear (to me) that it can't be a circle centered at some other point.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah, fair point.

Comment: I haven't really dug deep into how to solve this (until now) and I see now that my guess is wrong by miles.

Comment: @pisoir The fact that Catenary is at both ends pointing at an angle, but this arc is at both ends pointing perfectly vertical, indicates to me the two curves are probably unrelated.

Comment: Perhaps you would enjoy an introductory text on synthetic geometry. You see constructions with this type of constraint a lot there, and calculus often isn't necessary.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[image]

Let $O$ be the center of the square, and let $\ell(\theta)$ be the line through $O$ that makes an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal line.
The line $\ell(\theta)$ intersects with the lower side of the square at a point $M_\theta$, with
$OM_\theta=\dfrac{a}{2\sin \theta }$. So, if $N_\theta$ is the other end of our 'rotating' diagonal then we have 
$$ON_\theta=\rho(\theta)=h-OM_\theta=a\sqrt{2}-\dfrac{a}{2\sin \theta }.$$
Now, the area traced by $ON_\theta$ as $\theta$ varies between $\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$ is our desired area augmented by the area of the quarter of the square. So, the desired area is
$$\eqalign{
\mathcal{A}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\rho^2(\theta)\,d\theta-\frac{a^2}{4}\cr
&=a^2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\left(\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2\sin\theta}\right)^2\,d\theta-\frac{a^2}{4}
&=a^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\sqrt{2}\ln(1+\sqrt{2})\right)
}
$$
Therefore, the correct answer is about $13.6\%$ larger than the conjectured answer.

Comment: why do we square $ ON_{\theta}$ in the integral?

Answer (score 61):

I found this problem interesting enough to make a little animation along the line of @Blue's diagram (but I didn't want to edit their answer without permission):

[image]

*Mathematica* syntax for those who are interested:

```
G[d_, t_] := {t - (d t)/Sqrt[1 + t^2], d /Sqrt[1 + t^2]}
P[c_, m_] := Show[ParametricPlot[G[# Sqrt[8], t], {t, -4, 4}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Hue[#]}, PlotRange -> {{-1.025, 1.025}, {-.025, 
               2 Sqrt[2] + 0.025}}] & /@ (Range[m]/m), 
 ParametricPlot[G[Sqrt[8], t], {t, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}], 
 Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0, 1}, .025], Opacity[0.1], Rectangle[{-1, 0}, {1, 2}],
           Opacity[1], Line[{{c, 0}, G[Sqrt[8], c]}], Disk[{c, 0}, .025],
           {Hue[#], Disk[G[# Sqrt[8], c], .025]} & /@ (Range[m]/m)}],
 Axes -> False]
Manipulate[P[c, m], {c, -1, 1}, {m, 1, 20, 1}]
```

Comment: *Very* nice! I'd certainly let you add it to my answer, but I'd prefer it stand alone so that you can get up-votes.

Comment: ooooh shiny. +1

Comment: That's beautiful! +1

Comment: We can also forget about the square, and then let this segment rotate even further, its "foot" running along the $x$-axis and its direction such that it always points to the "focus" $(0,b)$ (notation from Blues answer). I wonder if the curve has a name.

Comment: @Blue it is amazing it got almost twice votes than your answer, but i am sure you are glad

Answer (score 33):

To avoid some fractions, I'll define $b := a/2$, so that the side of the square is $2b$ and its diagonal has length $2b\sqrt{2}$. Position the square so that its bottom lies on the $x$-axis, and its center lies on the $y$ axis (specifically, at $(0,b)$).

A tilted diagonal determines a line through $(0,b)$ and, say, $(c,0)$, with $c$ some parameter such that $-b \leq c \leq b$. Such a line has equation
$$\frac{x}{c} + \frac{y}{b} = 1 \qquad \to \qquad x b + y c = b c \qquad (\star)$$
The upper endpoint, $(x,y)$, of the tilted diagonal is a distance $2b\sqrt{2}$ from $(c,0)$:
$$(x-c)^2 + y^2 = 8 b^2 \qquad (\star\star)$$
Eliminating $c$ from $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$ gives
$$x^2 = \frac{(y-b)^2 (8 b^2 - y^2)}{y^2}$$
This equation represents this graph:

[image]

The area of the portion above the square can be determined via this integral:

$$2\;\int_{2b}^{2b\sqrt{2}}\frac{y-b}{y}\sqrt{8b^2-y^2} \; dy = 2b^2 \left( \pi - 2 \sqrt{2} \log( 1 + \sqrt{2} ) \right) = a^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \sqrt{2} \log(1+\sqrt{2})\right)$$
which agrees with both @OmranKouba and @IanMateus.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really an answer, but I wanted to record my observation that the curve in question is not actually a circle.

Let's say the square has corners at $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ so that the center is at the origin (and the diagonal has length $\sqrt{8}$).  If we fix a point $(s,-1)$ on the lower edge of the square, the line through $(s,-1)$ and $(0,0)$ is parametrized by $t \mapsto (-ts, t)$.  The point on this line which is distance $\sqrt{8}$ from $(s,-1)$ corresponds to $t$ being the positive solution of
$$(-ts-s)^2+(t+1)^2=8$$
which is
$$t = -1 + \sqrt{\frac{8}{s^2+1}}.$$
So the curve is parametrized by 
$$(x(s),y(s)) = \left( s - s\sqrt{\frac{8}{s^2+1}}, -1+\sqrt{\frac{8}{s^2+1}}\right).$$
If this is indeed a circle, by symmetry its center must be on the $y$-axis at some point $(0, y_0)$ in which case we must have
$$x(s)^2 + (y(s)-y_0)^2 = \text{const}$$
or, differentiating,
$$2 x(s) x'(s) + 2 (y(s)-y_0) y'(s) = 0.$$
Solving, we find that we must have
$$y_0 = \frac{x(s) x'(s)}{y'(s)} + y(s).$$
But this is not constant.  When $s=0$ the right side is $\frac{4-\sqrt{2}}{4}$ while if $s=1$ we get $1$.

Answer (score 3):

[image: math stuff?]

I'm not like super expert at math, and I only kind of checked my work, but I'm pretty sure this crudely-drawn msPaint picture is correct.

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, the fact that you thought this was posting *after all the other awesome answers* (and with that ridiculous disclaimer, no less!) is hilarious. I mean, kudos on getting an answer that agrees with Omran Kouba's, but...really?

Answer (score 1):

(Misinterpreted question, working on the correct version), the second part still holds.

**The other question:**

> Does this have any meaning? Have I been wandering around thinking about complete nonsense for so many years?

I am not sure what you mean, to me all math is meaningful. There is no such thing as meaningless in math, unless you write something obviously absurd  like

$$\frac{1}{8}- \text{tomato} = ??$$

Now, yours  is certainly a valid question, with some applications in engineering, I presume. Sure the above calculation isn't ground breaking -- fairly elementary in fact -- but it could come up.

Also, I do see some hints and traces of the [Isoperimetric problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) which discusses how efficient a shape is at enclosing an area, and circles happen to be the most efficient, a property that translates into volume-area efficiency in spheres -- which is the reason behind why all major celestial bodies are (almost) spheres, why bubbles are spherical, why raindrops are spherical, et cetera.

Comment: It won't be a circle. At the vertices, the distance from the centre of the square is $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$, in the middle of each arc, the distance is $(\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2})a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer he isn't rotating it about the centre?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I see, he is keeping the other end of the diagonal within the sqaure.

Comment: Within the square, you mean. Yes.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I mean square.

Comment: I object to the example. $\frac{1}{8}-\text{tomato}$ makes sense in any additive abelian group containing $\frac{1}{8}$ and a tomato.

Comment: @kigen sure what the hell. Everything makes sense. I considered $\text{tomato}$ can be a variable, pretty much the same.

Comment: @kigen: Practically, I am aware of systems in which `1/8`, `tomato` and addition are well defined (cookbooks, for example). However, I am unaware of any system in which `1/8`, `tomato` and the `-` operator are all well defined.

Comment: @dotancohen - $\mathbb{Q}[$tomato$]$

Comment: @user73985 why do we *insist* on $\text{tomato}$ making sense, when in fact that was *clearly* not the point of the answer.

Comment: @Sabyasachi We insist on things making sense because we are human, making things make sense is what we do, and is the defining characteristic of humanity.

Comment: @corsiKa such philosophy. many touching. wow.